# Checking that a line bundle generated by global section is positive

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

Let $L\rightarrow X$ be a holomorphic line bundle generated by global sections $s_1,...,s_k$. One can define a Hermitian metric on $L$ by
$$|s|^2 = \dfrac{|\psi(s)|^2}{\sum_i |\psi(s_i)|^2}$$
in a local trivialization $\psi$.

I am wondering how to prove that the curvature of this metric is positive by a straightforward computation, that is computing
$$-i\partial\bar{\partial}\log(1/\sum_i |\psi(s_i)|^2)$$
and showing it is indeed a positive (1,1) form. I am getting into obscure expressions. Can someone tell me what I am supposed to get?

EDIT: So it's not actually hard: we have though for any holomorphic function $f$
$$\partial\bar{\partial}\log|f|^2 = \partial\left(\frac{\bar{\partial}|f|^2}{|f|^2} \right) =\partial\left(\frac{f\bar{\partial}\bar{f}}{|f|^2} \right) \\
=\partial\left(\frac{f}{|f|^2} \right)\wedge \bar{\partial}\bar{f}=
\partial\left(\frac{1}{\bar{f}} \right)\wedge \bar{\partial}\bar{f}=0$$
which kills my expression above. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Where does the second expression comes from?

Comment: @DanielPlácido between parentheses is the matrix (in this case a scalar) of the metric in the trivialization

Comment: The sum of squares of moduli of holomorphic functions is generally not the square of the modulus of a single holomorphic function. Thus your edit does not apply.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon yes right, but I still dont understand why I get 0, the log|.|^2 should be plurisubharmonic

Comment: If you compute directly you’ll see that your form can be written locally as $\sum i \partial \bar \partial |f_i|^2$, where the $f_i$ are holomorphic. You’ll have to convince yourself this is a sum of semipositive forms. Globally generated only gets you that, for positivity you need ampleness (that is, the sections need to separate 1-jets globally as well).

Comment: I tried putting my money where my mouth is and quickly realized this gets more complicated than I’m painting it. The least painful way I know of doing this is: (1) Prove that $O(1)$ on $\mathbb P^n$ is positive by using symmetry to reduce to the case of a well chosen point and computing directly. (2) Observe that a globally generated bundle $L$ on $X$ defines a map $X \to \mathbb P^n$ such that $O(1)$ pulls back to $L$. Thus the curvature form of $L$ (which you wrote down) is the pullback of the Fubini-Study form by a holomorphic map, and is thus semipositive.

Comment: did you forget the term $\frac{f}{|f|^2} \partial \bar{\partial} \bar{f}$ after the 3rd and 4th equalities, or does it vanish?